# System.InvalidOperationException setting texbox text

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms, user-interface, invalidoperationexception

I am using one thread running this code:

```
try
{
    Form1 f = getForm<Form1>();
    f.changePrice(price);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("error: " + e);
}
```

Here is the `changePrice` method:

```
public void changePrice(Int32 price)
{
   txtPrice.Text = ""+price;
}
```

I want to add text to my textbox "txtPrice".

Comment: Add an empty string to an integer ? Start some reading please.

Comment: Is the `changePrice` used by the same thread which `owns` the `Form1`? You can't change properties of a `Control` from other thread that way.

Comment: it is being used from another thread, any suggestions Kamil?

Comment: You can't do it that way, use the way described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-the-gui-from-another-thread-in-c

Comment: What *exactly* does the error message say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your textbox text at runtime like this.

```
public void changePrice(Int32 price)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<Int32>(changePrice), new object[] { price });
            return;
        }

        txtPrice.Text = ""+ price;          
    }
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: you should see the answers in this question, pretty much explains it..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614157/help-with-understanding-c-sharp-syntax-while-invoking-a-new-action

Answer (score 1):

convert it to `string` as `Text` property is of type `string`:

```
public void changePrice(Int32 price)
{
   txtPrice.Text = price.ToString();

}
```

Comment: That's not necessary, all C# built-in types can be implicitly converted to string, there's no need to do it manually.

Comment: i did'nt got what you are trying to say, Op is setting Text of TExtBox and it requires ``String`` not ``Int``

Comment: `TextBox.Text` is a `string` object and you can use (for example) `string _Text = "partOfString"+5;`. The compiler will merge the `"partOfString"+5` into a string itself, because `Int32` is implicitly converted to string. It will work as long as there is a piece of string in the expression. OP's approach, the `txtPrice.Text = ""+price;` is surely not neat, but still it's not the main issue.

Comment: ok.. thanks for correcting me, i was not aware of this behaviour

Comment: I am still getting a invalidoperationexception. It says "action across threads is invalid"

Comment: what is the definition of ``getForm()`` ??