# Lambda expression with empty paren ()

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I came across code like:

```
var vpAlias = null;
var prices = session.QueryOver<Vehicle>()
    .Left.JoinAlias<VehiclePrice>(x => x.VehiclePrice, () => vpAlias, x => x.VehiclePriceTypeId == 1)
    .Where(() => vpAlias.Id == null || vpAlias.VehiclePriceTypeId == 1)
    .Select(x => x.Id, () => vpAlias.Price)
    .ToList();
```

that uses `()` in its lambda expressions. What does that mean ? Is it used just as a placeholder ?

Comment: `var vpAlias = null;` is not allowed!

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6614157/help-with-understanding-c-sharp-syntax-while-invoking-a-new-action

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It just means it's an empty parameter list - for delegate types which don't have any parameters.

The fact that you can write `x => x.Id` is really just a shorthand for `(x) => x.Id` which is in turn a shorthand for `(Vehicle x) => x.Id`. It's just a parameter list.

Comment: Well explained sir...I was. not aware of this.. .is this mentioned in your book?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Lambda expressions are in general (section 9.1). I'm not sure whether I specifically talk about an empty parameter list.

Comment: Can you tell in which case we pass empty parameter?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: It's not a matter of "passing" an empty parameter - it's any time you want to use a delegate with no parameters, e.g. `Func<int>`.

Answer (score 4):

It is the same as the empty `()` in:

```
static SomeType YourNamedMethod()
{
   return vpAlias;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The parentheses contain the parameter list. Only if you have exactly 1 parameter can you leave them off.
Examples:

0 parameters: `() => result`

1 parameter: `(x) => result or x => result`

2 parameters: `(x, y) => x + y;`

Answer (score 1):

`() => { ... }` is a `Func<TOut>`, so it does not take anything as input, you can see it as a

```
<returnType> MyFunction () { // Code goes here }
```

Comment: Not necessarily a `Func` it can be any. For example `Action`.

Comment: Thats right, but in the OP's question its always Func<T>, so i didn't go for Action :)